# Modules not found in python project?

Tags: python, pycharm, tweepy

I have a python project in Pycharm.  The code looks like this:

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
from kafka import SimpleProducer, KafkaClient

access_token = "56078905-nIhiZaeN6pe2GeNvppxItmO6ap6YYXKXfqqAjqt8f"
access_token_secret =  "2ZD1RENb7jvXgR7TmDu6pKcgliCC3du89jG7hTibfeTI6"
consumer_key =  "e8vFKglSgPeMFueUXX4e2bglB"
consumer_secret =  "O85aPvR1u42NLinbjRbbmAb0ajN6gTVZXB4uGXfhASBdTda7jv"

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        producer.send_messages("trump", data.encode('utf-8'))
        print (data)
        return True
    def on_error(self, status):
        print (status)

kafka = KafkaClient("localhost:9092")
producer = SimpleProducer(kafka)
l = StdOutListener()
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
stream = Stream(auth, l)
stream.filter(track="trump")
```

However when I run this I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nke09/kafkatest/twitterkafka.py", line 3, in <module>
    from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from tweepy.models import Status, User, DirectMessage, Friendship, SavedSearch, SearchResults, ModelFactory, Category
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/models.py", line 7, in <module>
    from tweepy.utils import parse_datetime, parse_html_value, parse_a_href
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    import six
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six'
```

I don't understand because I do have six installed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your case would be that, you might have chosen a `virtual env` for this particular project instead of choosing an existing interpreter. so, go to `Settings-->Project Interpreter` and then choose the existing python interpreter from the options. But, i think before doing this, you should first do `pip install six` and check if its really installed

Answer (score 0):

From pycharm,

goto `settings` -> `project Interpreter`

Check whether `six` is installed. If it is installed already you can see in the table. If not installed,

Click on `+` button on top right corner and you will get pop-up window of Available packages. Then search for `six` python package.

Then click on `Install package` to install the package

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check that your module six is installed for python2 or python3
**Use Pip3 for python3** and **use pip for python2** maybe it will help you